# How to build an interface that plots an equation given as text by a user?

Tags: plotting, dynamic, inputfield

I would like to create a window where a student may enter an equation and, by clicking on a button, the function gets plotted.

---

In the original Spanish:

> Quiero realizar una ventana en la cual el alumno tenga la opción de ingresar una ecuación la cual al presionar un botón se grafique.

Comment: Sorry, but this question is totally incomprehensible. You might even do better to ask in Spanish, rather than using wrongly machine-translated English that nobody can understand. // Lo sentimos, pero esta cuestión es totalmente incomprensible. Incluso puede ser mejor preguntar en español, en lugar de la máquina incorrecta traducido Inglés que nadie puede entender.

Comment: Although I really like your language, it is convenient to write in English on this site. Would you mind to translate it for us?

Comment: Perhaps you can use [`DialogInput`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DialogInput.html).

Comment: @MichaelE2 I hijacked the edit and changed "function" to "equation".

Comment: @halirutan sorry--I thought it would probably be better for the OP to ask in a language in which she can produce a coherent question and rely on someone else to translate, rather than writing in hopelessly broken English. I realise that this isn't completely ideal, but it gives us all the best chance of being able to communicate. If the questions aren't any good for other reasons, that's another issue, of course.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I appreciate that my suggestion might not be to everyone's taste, but there seemed to be at least some justification for it in [this](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/708/2012-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest/723#723) discussion. Specifically, it was motivated by the fact that Google Translate actually does a terrible job in this case, which led to her other questions being absolutely senseless.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Ah, I didn't know that. I guess it is really hard for us (and especially the mods) then to understand the question, although it is perfectly clear in its language. Since I guessed that the OP probably is better in her native language, I didn't downvote or voted to close. I just left the comment.

Comment: I have re-opened this question after Oleksandr's edit.  Jenny, in the future please make edits to your question rather than posting a new question separately.  If a question is marked "[on hold]" it should not be abandoned; instead it should be edited to make it a better question.  I hope that you are able to read this comment.

Comment: To Jenny: You can also ask for help in the chat, where people who speak Spanish can help you write down your question in English, or simply help you with your problem. There are almost always Spanish-speakers in the chat. / Puedes preguntar alguien en el chat también, a menudo hay alguien allí que habla español.

Comment: Ok,sorry by my bad english :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Panel[DynamicModule[{f = Sin[x^2]}, 
  Column[{InputField[Dynamic[f]], Dynamic[Plot[f, {x, -5, 5}]]}]]]
```

or even simpler

```
Manipulate[Plot[f, {x, -5, 5}], {f, Sin[x^2]}]
```

[image]

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do with your students. But if the goal is to spare them programming Plot[...] etc., you could just use **[free form linguistic input](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-8/free-form-linguistic-input/)** (or go to [**Wolfram|Alpha**](http://wolfr.am/m9URcH)). The advantage is students wouldn't have to know strict syntax for functions:

[image]

Comment: If that's what I want, but instead of putting Sin in English, Spanish put in Seno

Comment: @JennyOjeda pretendes demasiado. WolframAlpha puede entender código en lenguaje natural pero sólo en inglés por ahora. / You are hoping for too much. I believe WolframAlpha for now can only interpret natural input in English

Comment: @JennyOjeda Yes for now W|A is English only, but I thought mathematical symbols are universal: sin(x) is that in any language

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov $余弦^2(x) + 正弦^2(x) = 1$ :D

Comment: I need to make a window in mathematica, it is the only software i can handle, and I would add that textfield in which you enter the abbreviated function Seno ie Sen (x) and i don´t know how to convert.

Comment: I'm trying to make a window in which students can learn as it is a graphical changes position, without being connected to internet, only to be locally institution level, I require an application in Mathematica (which is the only language allowed to teach in the subject)